# How to hide intellisense warnings from include qt header files

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2019

I'm using visual studio 2019 with the qt add in. Everything works fine but I get really annoyed by all the warnings that are thrown towards me. The warnings I get arise from the qt headers that I include in my project. I have searched online and it seems that more people have this problem, but I can not seem to find a solution which helps or which I can follow.

I've seen a solution in which they add something to the qmake.conf file, but I don't know where to find the correct qmake.conf file. Since I have many folders in the mkspecs directory. Furthermore this solution seems to me as if it would solve build warnings and not intellisense warnings, but I'm not sure about that.

I have also seen something about using pragma, but I don't really understand what to do with that.

They way I include the qt headers is with:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QTreeWidget>
```

Ultimately I would just like to tell intellisense to not check the external dependencies folder (which I know is not an actual directory). Alternatively I would just like to tell intellisense not to look in the (actual) folder Qt\5.13.0\msvc2017\include.

Can somebody please help me in a clear way. I'm new to using visual studio as well as using QT. So please provide a clear procedure which I can easily follow.

Comment: Related but not solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697129/how-can-i-suppress-intellisense-errors-for-certain-files/35786770

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try surrounding your QT #includes with pragmas to disable whatever warnings the QT header files generate, something like:

```
#pragma warning (push)
#pragma warning (disable: 1234 5678 ...)

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QTreeWidget>

#pragma warning (pop)
```

Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=vs-2019)

Comment: I think this solves build warnings not Intellisense.

Comment: @drescherjm Apparently it does.

Comment: @PaulSanders With qt there are also autogenerated files. I can not keep adding the pragmas there.

Comment: Do you need to look inside these files, if they are auto-generated?

Comment: @PaulSanders No I don't. I just put the the autogenerated files (ui_name.h) also in between the pragma's and then it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can now use Clang-Tidy with visual studio 2019. you just need to enable clang -tidy and disable MicrosoftCodeAnalysis in the project properties in code analysis. this will give a more qt creator like intellisense.
[ms documentation for clang - tidy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/clang-tidy?view=vs-2019)
This will get rid of all the warnings in the qt library. you will need to restart visual studio for the changes to appear